# Eclipse Luna marketplace

Tags: termination, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-luna

I've just installed Eclipse Luna v4.4.0 and trying to access marketplace.
During load Eclipse fails, reports nothing to stderr and terminates.
I'm using no proxy if that means.

Does anybody met any bug like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some bugs with Eclipse Luna and the Marketplace Client.  You should follow the instructions here to get the fixed version.

https://www.eclipse.org/mpc/

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution somewhere (it works with Luna and Mars too):
Add line:

`org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4`

into

<your eclipse folder>/configuration/config.ini

And restart eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug for Eclipse LUNA.

[bug-422665](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422665)

But htere is a work around.

- Go to eclipse Luna installed folder/Plugin/
- take backupo of this two below files
  `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl_1.0.0.v20141221-2352.jar`
  `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4_1.0.1043.v20141221-2352.jar`
- Copy corresponding two files form eclipse-Kipler/Plugin folder if you have already installed it. or can search online.
  `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl_1.0.0.v20130604-1622.jar`
  `org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4_1.0.300.v20130604-1622.jar`
- Start Eclipse now.

Worked for me and many others.  THis is just a work around and not a permanent solution.

Hope this Helps.